# linear algebra about isomorphism

Tags: linear-algebra

The two dimensional standard vector space is not a subspace of the three dimensional standard vector space. Give three distinct subspaces of $\mathbb C^3$ that are isomorphic to $\mathbb C^2$.

Comment: One of them is the $x$-$y$ plane.

Comment: Another is the $x$-$z$ plane. ;)

Comment: can you explain with more details?

Comment: Consider the set of vectors of the shape $(a,b,0)$. This is a vector subspace of ordinary three-dimensional space. The mapping that takes $(a,b,0)$ to $(a,b)$ is a vector space isomorphism.

Answer (score 1):

The $xy$-plane, the $yz$-plane, and the $zx$-plane are three distinct subspaces of $\mathbb R^3$ that are isomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$.

For example, the $yz$-plane is the set of all points for which $x=0$; that is, $\{(0,s,t):s\in\mathbb R,t\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: dear jasper,can you explain more specificly?please,give me example about it